# In Tablayout I have added some tab and in that when I am switching between the tabs fragment refreshes its data? Why?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

```
private Boolean isStarted = false;
private Boolean isVisible = false;

@Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        isStarted = true;
        if (isVisible && isStarted){
            loadData();
        }

}
//
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    isVisible = isVisibleToUser;
    if (isVisible && isStarted) {
        loadData();
    }
}
```

what i am trying to do is when I launch the app data comes from db and shown in tab1 when i click on tab2 it again hits db and bring data and display. The problem arise when i came back to tab1 then it again hits db and bring data and again sets data in tab1 but its data is already loaded.

I already set the `viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);`.

Need help?
Thanks

Comment: how manny Fragments are u add in to viewPager?

Comment: only 1 fragment I have added and tabs are 4. all queries are similar in fragment and only the title of is different so I am reusing the same fragment.

Comment: Even if you reuse the fragment, different instances are created. Set offScreenPageLimit to number of fragments.

Comment: by setting `viewPager.setoffscreenPageLimit(fragmentcount)` is not working.

Comment: Post your MainActivity code where you add Fragments

Comment: The problem is when I set `viewPager.setoffscreenPageLimit(fragmentcount)` then it loads data for all tabs at once that I don't want. I want only the data is loaded when I visit the fragment and I will keeping data only for last visited tab only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Solved the Problem.
Just need to set the `isStarted = false;` and `isVisible = false;` and that worked. Thanks Guys for helping me.

```
set `isStarted = false;` and `isVisible = false;` inside `loadData();`
```

Answer (score 0):

As @Mohit Suthar says Its default behaviours of ViewPager, its hold only two fragments at a time,so you can change as follow

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
```

to

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(FragmentCount);  //apply limit of how many you take fragment to prevent re create View
```

Answer (score 0):

Its default behaviours of **ViewPager**, its hold only two fragments at a time, if you want to load all the fragment in all time then you should go with **setOffscreenPageLimit()**, set the maximum of the limit of view pager item that you want to show. After then your fragment is not being refreshed.

You override this **setUserVisibleHint()** method remove this method and call loadData() data in **onViewCreated()** method, 
Because **setUserVisibleHint()** call every time when your fragment is on **screen**.

```
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(MAX_FRAGMENT);
```

Comment: what you are saying is correct but it will load data for all tabs. that I don't want.